# Problema cálculo media aritmética Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy empezando con Javascript y tengo problemas a la hora de calcular la media aritmética en este ejercicio, el enunciado es el siguiente:

Hay que hacer un script que pida números hasta que pulsemos "cancelar". Si lo que introducimos no es un número, nos debe indicar con un mensaje que lo que hemos introducido es incorrecto y que nos siga pidiendo. Al salir, nos debe dar la suma total de lo introducido y la media.

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Este es el código que llevo:

```
<script>
    var suma = 0;

    do{
        var numero = prompt("Introduce un número, pulse Cancelar si no quiere seguir");
        if(Number(numero)== numero){
            numero = Number(numero);
            suma = suma + numero;
            for(i=0; i<numero.length; i++){
                i = suma / numero.length;
            }
        }

        else{
            if(numero!=undefined){
                alert("El número introducido "+ numero+" no es correcto");
            }
        }
    }while (numero!=undefined);
        
    document.write("La suma de los números son: "+suma+"<br>");
    document.write("La media de los números introducidos son: "+i);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La mayor parte de los errores que está cometiendo tiene que ver con la lógica, por ejemplo, para la media usted está dividiendo la suma de los números con `numero.length` (Number no cuenta con .length), cuando ahí debe de ir la cantidad de números ingresados, puede crear un contador para esto.

Debe convertir las entradas a `Number` debido a que éstas vienen como tipo `String`, pero también debe manejar los errores en caso de que estos no puedan ser convertidos a números de forma correcta. En caso de que la entrada no pueda ser convertida a número la variable tomará el valor de `NaN`.

Por definición, `NaN` es el valor devuelto de las operaciones que tienen un resultado numérico indefinido. Por lo tanto, porque, en JavaScript, además de formar parte del objeto global, también forma parte del objeto Number: Number.NaN. Sigue siendo un tipo de datos numérico,pero no está definido como un número real. Para más información puede ir a: [NaN and typeof](https://javascriptrefined.io/nan-and-typeof-36cd6e2a4e43#:%7E:text=By%20definition%2C%20NaN%20is%20the%20return%20value%20from,but%20it%20is%20undefined%20as%20a%20real%20number.)

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      let suma = 0;
      let media = 0;
      let contador = 0;
      let entrada = null;
      do {
        entrada = prompt(
          "Introduce un número, pulse Cancelar si no quiere seguir: "
        );
        // Salir del ciclo en el caso de que se de click en Cancelar
        if (entrada === null) break;
        // Convertir a Number
        let numero = parseFloat(entrada);
        // Puede ver en consola el valor de numero
        console.log(numero);
        // True si la conversión no fue posible
        if (isNaN(numero)) {
          alert("El valor introducido " + entrada + " no es un numero");
        } else {
          // Se ejecuta sólo si la entrada pudo ser convertida a un número
          contador++;
          suma = suma + numero;
          media = suma / contador;
        }
        // Confirmar si el usuario desea seguir ingresando datos. Confirm retorna true (OK) o false (Cancel)
        if (confirm("¿Desea seguir ingresando datos?")) {
        } else break;
      } while (entrada !== null);
      // Si no ingresó ningún dato
      if (entrada === null) {
        document.write("No se ingresaron datos, el programa finalizó");
      } else {
        document.write("La suma de los números es: " + suma + "<br>");
        document.write(
          "La media de los números introducidos son: " + media.toFixed(2)
        );
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Nota: Pruebe ejecutar el código en otra parte, ya que, pareciera ser que hoy (15/03/2021) esta funcionalidad de la plataforma está teniendo problemas.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Ahora lo veo claro y efectivamente estaba confundiendo conceptos. Un saludo.

Comment: Listo Miriam. Un saludo.